# Copy raster exif in GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, exif, rasterio

I have two images with the same size - first one is an image from a drone and the second - a mask. I need to subtract both images and of course translate the exif data from the original image into the resulting one. Is it possible in gdal or rasterio?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with DJI drones, the aerial imagery is often captured in JPEG format. The metadata can be accessed through GDAL like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal 
im = gdal.Open('ImageName.jpg', 0)
exif = im.GetMetadata()
```

This returns a Python dictionary containing the EXIF metadata. To copy the metadata to a new image, you can simply do this:

```
outimg = im.GetDriver().CreateCopy('NewImageName.jpg', im, callback=gdal.TermProgress_nocb)
outimg.SetMetadata(exif)
del im, outimg, exif  # close datasets to commit changes to disk
```

You can then edit the newly created image as required (e.g., multiply pixel values by binary mask).